# How to correctly check the host: Office, Office online and web browser

Tags: office-js

I need to detect whether a user has hit the URL of my add-in from a browser, **outside** of Office and Office online. (I've seen questions here about detecting whether it is Excel, or Excel online, but not *neither* of them.)

I've looked at the utility functions `OfficeHelpers.Utilities.host` and `OfficeHelpers.Utilities.isAddin` but the [code notes](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/blob/master/src/helpers/utilities.ts) say these will only work after Office.initialize is called. If the URL has been navigated to from outside of an Office client then this won't be the case (?).

So I think I need to perform the same check as whatever is being done when you get the warning:
[Warning in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69fam.png)
...to make sure that the Office.initialize will not be run, not that it hasn't run *yet*.

A simple use of this, would be to direct users to a page that displays explains they cannot access this without loading it as an add-in, and instructions on how to load the add-in etc.

The actual result I am trying to get is to handle both cases as:

From within an Office client: "GetData" will return some values and write them to a document.
If accessed from a browser: "GetData" will return some values and redirect to a View to display these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no great solution for this at the moment, though I agree that there is an opportunity here to expose an "Office.ready" to provide a definitive sign that Office.js loaded one way or another -- and that the host and platform are now stably determined (including determined to be stably "web" and null).

For [Script Lab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab), we use the approach of waiting on Office.js for three seconds, and then giving up and displaying a disambuguation set of buttons to the user, asking them to choose the host.  We could probably safely assume "web" at that point, but in our case we want to provide a disambiguation experience in any case, so users can choose whether to run web snippets or view host-specific ones where they would need a host choice anyway.

If you're curious to see how it is done, see the "initialize"  function in https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/eeb4ba89a7a570cf1bb035fdd740ec7dcfb92822/src/client/app/helpers/environment.ts

Comment: Is this still how you'd approach it, out of interest?

Comment: Re. the initialize function, you can simplify the logic with a recently-released feature, the `Office.onReady` API.  See https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/5#issuecomment-382189046